# Get count grouped by month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi everybody i have the next query

```
DECLARE @fechaInicio AS VARCHAR(10) 
DECLARE @fechaFin AS VARCHAR(10) 
DECLARE @codGestor AS VARCHAR(10) 
DECLARE @codSponsor AS VARCHAR(10) 
DECLARE @codProducto AS VARCHAR(10)

SET @fechaInicio = '20140101' 
SET @fechaFin = '20141231' 
SET @codGestor = 'BDOBRASIL' 
SET @codSponsor = 'MARCH' 
SET @codProducto = 8


SELECT 
   COUNT(crt_numinterno_id) * 100.00 / pnc_cantidad AS Ventas,
   prd_descripcion, 
   DATENAME(MM, crt_fecinivige) + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(crt_fecinivige) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS crt_fecinivige, 
   C.prd_producto_id,pnc_cantidad 
FROM Certificados C 
INNER JOIN Penetracion P 
   ON C.ges_gestor_id = P.ges_gestor_id 
   AND C.spo_sponsor_id = P.spo_sponsor_id 
   AND C.prd_producto_id = P.prd_producto_id 
LEFT JOIN Productos R 
   ON C.ges_gestor_id = R.ges_gestor_id 
   AND C.spo_sponsor_id = R.spo_sponsor_id 
   AND C.prd_producto_id = R.prd_producto_id 
WHERE C.ges_gestor_id = @codGestor 
   AND C.spo_sponsor_id = @codSponsor 
   AND (@codProducto = '' OR @codProducto = C.prd_producto_id) 
   AND crt_fechabaja IS NULL 
   AND crt_fecinivige BETWEEN @fechaInicio AND @fechaFin 
GROUP BY 
   pnc_cantidad,
   prd_descripcion,
   DATENAME(MM, crt_fecinivige),
   YEAR(crt_fecinivige), 
   DATEPART(yyyy,crt_fecinivige),
   C.prd_producto_id,
   DATEPART(m,crt_fecinivige) 
ORDER BY 
   DATEPART(yyyy,crt_fecinivige),
   DATEPART(m,crt_fecinivige)
```

i get the next result check the image

[image]

all was good but i only get `Ventas` for September and my boss want see all months between `@fechaInicio` and `@fechaFin` and i don't know how grouping all months

Comment: im new in sql server i only know easy query insert, update, delete. Can you tell me how do that?

Comment: Make your code easy to read please.

Comment: well somebody did for me. I see some examples with table from dates but i don't know how make that isn't clear this examples

Comment: In the select try to change this:

COUNT(crt_numinterno_id) * 100.00 / pnc_cantidad AS Ventas,
   prd_descripcion, 
   DATENAME(MM, crt_fecinivige) + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(crt_fecinivige) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS crt_fecinivige, 
   C.prd_producto_id,pnc_cantidad 

For This : Distinct Month(crt_fecinivige),Year(crt_fecinivige)

And tell me your results please

Comment: well i only got 1 row and this is: 9 | 2014 

that's all

Comment: That is becouse you only have data from september, you should try to verify your where.

Comment: Yes i know, i only have data in september but i need to display all months and if i don't have data in that months show zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a common table expression to generate a table with a sequence of months and then use that to left join your query with. In this example I used `20140101` as the date that determines the start of the range. Please give it a try.

```
;WITH cte (dt) AS (
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, v.number, '20140101') 
FROM master..spt_values v 
WHERE
   v.number >= 0 AND
   v.number < 12 AND
   v.type = 'p'
)

SELECT 
    Ventas, 
    prd_descripcion,
    COALESCE(crt_fecinivige, DATENAME(MM, dt) + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(dt) AS VARCHAR(4))),
    prd_producto_id, 
    pnc_cantidad    
FROM cte c

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(crt_numinterno_id) * 100.00 / pnc_cantidad AS Ventas,
      prd_descripcion, 
      DATENAME(MM, crt_fecinivige) + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(crt_fecinivige) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS crt_fecinivige, 
      C.prd_producto_id,
      pnc_cantidad 
    FROM Certificados C 
    INNER JOIN Penetracion P 
      ON C.ges_gestor_id = P.ges_gestor_id 
      AND C.spo_sponsor_id = P.spo_sponsor_id 
      AND C.prd_producto_id = P.prd_producto_id 
    LEFT JOIN Productos R 
      ON C.ges_gestor_id = R.ges_gestor_id 
      AND C.spo_sponsor_id = R.spo_sponsor_id 
      AND C.prd_producto_id = R.prd_producto_id 
    WHERE C.ges_gestor_id = @codGestor 
      AND C.spo_sponsor_id = @codSponsor 
      AND (@codProducto = '' OR @codProducto = C.prd_producto_id) 
      AND crt_fechabaja IS NULL 
      AND crt_fecinivige BETWEEN @fechaInicio AND @fechaFin 
    GROUP BY 
      pnc_cantidad,
      prd_descripcion,
      DATENAME(MM, crt_fecinivige),
      YEAR(crt_fecinivige), 
      DATEPART(yyyy,crt_fecinivige),
      C.prd_producto_id,
      DATEPART(m,crt_fecinivige) 
) a ON c.dt = a.crt_fecinivige
ORDER BY 
    DATEPART(yyyy,crt_fecinivige) DESC,
    DATEPART(m,crt_fecinivige) DESC
```

Comment: Hi thanks for it that work good but i wanna show all months in the range for example 1 january 2013 to 1 december 2014 that's possible?

Comment: This query work perfect but only show all months in 2014 for example but if i put 2015 not display it.

Comment: @Ryuzaki If you want another range just change the hard coded date in the `DATEADD(MONTH, v.number, '20140101')` to whenever you want your range to start, and change the `v.number < 12` (the number of months to add from the start) to the number of months you want.

Comment: So `DATEADD(MONTH, v.number, '20130101')` and `v.number < 24` for 20130101 to 20141201.

Comment: That work but i need this range dynamic so i put v.number <= (SELECT DATEDIFF (MONTH , @fechaInicio , @fechaFin)) and work now dynamically